# No se valida la condición dada (juego interactivo en C - ahorcado)

Tags: c, condiciones, bucles

Hola que tal gente de stack overflow, el día de hoy les quiero hacer una pequeña consulta...
Sucede que esta semana he estado trabajando con algoritmos en C para diseñar un pequeño "juego" basado en Ascii-art que recrea el juego del ahorcado, pues hasta ahora todo funcionaba bien, sin embargo, haciendo pruebas me di cuenta de un error de validación. En la función "play_mode" al validar si el usuario gano verificando el numero de intentos y si ya no hay niveles disponibles, no se valida y pasa al caso contrario, imprimiendo el mensaje equivocado...
¿Me pueden ayudar?

Código:
 - Función que causa el problema...
 - No toma como verdadera la ciondicion: 
"if (aciertos == 6 && verify_words () == 0 )"
y pasa directamente al else.

```
//jugar
int aciertos = 0;

int play_mode (){
    int i,j,lvl;
    int intento=0,respuesta=0;
    char op='x',so='x';

    lvl = randword ();

    do {
        system ("clear");
        ahorcado_dibujitos (intento);

        if (aciertos == 6 && verify_words () == 0 ){//si el usuario acerto en todas las palabras
            printf (" |Y| Has Ganado!!! \n |#| Completaste 6/6 palabras.\n");
            getchar ();
            break;
            return 0;
        }

        else if (aciertos < 6 && verify_words () == 0){//si el usuario acerto algunas y ya agoto las palabras
            printf (" |Y| Has perdido... :'( \n |#| Completaste %i/6 palabras.\n",aciertos);
            getchar ();
            break;
            return 0;
        }

        else {
            //palabra acertada.
            if (strcmp (Words[lvl].palabra_mostrar,Words[lvl].palabra) == 0){
                Words[lvl].avalible = 0;
                aciertos ++;
                printf ("|=============================================|\n");
                printf ("|/////////////////////////////////////////////|\n");
                printf ("|!| [Palabra completada!: [%s]      |\n",Words[lvl].palabra);
                printf ("|W| Palabras restantes [ %i ]                  |\n",verify_words ());
                printf ("|+| Puntnuacion [%i]                           |\n",aciertos);
                printf ("|/////////////////////////////////////////////|\n");
                printf ("|=============================================|\n");
                getchar ();
                break;
            }



            //palabra no acertada.
            else {//game over...
                if (intento == 6 ){
                    //imrimir ahorcado centrado
                    for (i=0;i<=7;i++){
                        printf ("       %s\n",W[i].ahorcado);
                    }
                    //menu de consolacion
                    printf ("|=============================================|\n");
                    printf ("|////////////| Te has equivocado |////////////|\n");
                    printf ("|/|-----------------------------------------|/|\n");
                    printf ("|/|           Quedan %i palabras...          |/|\n",verify_words ());
                    printf ("|/|    ¿Deseas continuar de igual forma?    |/|\n");
                    printf ("|/|-----------------------------------------|/|\n");
                    printf ("|////////////|     [Y] - [N]     |////////////|\n");
                    printf ("|=============================================|\n");
                        incorreco:
                    printf ("|opc| -> "); scanf ("%c",&so);

                        flush_in ();

                    if (so == 'Y' || so == 'y'){
                        //continuar
                        intento = 0;
                        Words[lvl].avalible = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (so == 'n' || so == 'N'){
                        //ir al menu
                        system ("clear");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        goto incorreco;
                    }
                }

                else {
                    //imrpimir ahorcado.
                    for (i=0;i<=7;i++){
                        printf ("%s\n",W[i].ahorcado);
                    }
                    printf("[   %s   ]\n",Words[lvl].palabra_mostrar);
                    printf("[   Digita una letra...  ]\n");
                    printf("\n[//> "); scanf("%c",&op );
                        flush_in ();

                    if (answ_tf (op,lvl) == 1){
                        printf ("\n |Y| Has acertado!");

                        getchar ();
                        answer (op,lvl);
                        system ("clear");
                    }
                    else {
                        printf ("\n |N| Te has equivocado!\n");
                        intento ++;
                        getchar ();
                    }
                }
            }



        }

    }while (intento < 7);

}
```

Comment: Me llama la atención que en el segundo else haces aciertos++ y luego un break.

Comment: Es posible que tal vez el valor de la variable aciertos este sobrepasando los 6 aciertos, en ese caso si que ha ganado la partida, solo que ha contado de mas, y no se toma como verdadera, prueba a poner en la condición el operador 'mayor o igual que' en vez de un 'igual'.

Comment: lo he intentado pero sigue sin tomar en cuenta el primer if, no e que me falta...

Comment: El contador llega a 6?

Comment: y has probado limpiar el buffer con fflush(stdin)??

Answer (score 0):

Pues logre resolver el error validando fuera del bucle while de la función.
Una vez el contador llegara a 7, el bucle se rompería y entonces pasaría a las siguientes instrucciones por lo que luego del bucle coloque el condicional y listo!!

```
do {
        system ("clear");
        ahorcado_dibujitos (intento);

            //palabra acertada.
            if (strcmp (Words[lvl].palabra_mostrar,Words[lvl].palabra) == 0){
                aciertos ++;
                printf ("|=============================================|\n");
                printf ("|/////////////////////////////////////////////|\n");
                printf ("|!| [Palabra completada!: [%s]      |\n",Words[lvl].palabra);
                printf ("|W| Palabras restantes [ %i ]                  |\n",verify_words ());
                printf ("|+| Puntnuacion [%i]                           |\n",aciertos);
                printf ("|/////////////////////////////////////////////|\n");
                printf ("|=============================================|\n");

                if (verify_words () == 1){
                    winner = 1;
                }

                getchar ();
                break;
            }
            //palabra no acertada.
            else {//game over...
                if (intento == 6 ){
                    //imrimir ahorcado centrado
                    for (i=0;i<=7;i++){
                        printf ("       %s\n",W[i].ahorcado);
                    }
                    //menu de consolacion
                    printf ("|=============================================|\n");
                    printf ("|////////////| Te has equivocado |////////////|\n");
                    printf ("|/|-----------------------------------------|/|\n");
                    printf ("|/|           Quedan %i palabras...          |/|\n",verify_words ());
                    printf ("|/|    ¿Deseas continuar de igual forma?    |/|\n");
                    printf ("|/|-----------------------------------------|/|\n");
                    printf ("|////////////|     [Y] - [N]     |////////////|\n");
                    printf ("|=============================================|\n");
                        incorreco:
                    printf ("|opc| -> "); scanf ("%c",&so);

                        flush_in ();

                    if (so == 'Y' || so == 'y'){
                        //continuar
                        intento = 0;
                        Words[lvl].avalible = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (so == 'n' || so == 'N'){
                        //ir al menu
                        system ("clear");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        goto incorreco;
                    }
                }

                else {
                    //imrpimir ahorcado.
                    for (i=0;i<=7;i++){
                        printf ("%s\n",W[i].ahorcado);
                    }

                    printf("[   %s   ]\n",Words[lvl].palabra_mostrar);
                    printf("[   Digita una letra...  ]\n");
                    printf("\n[//> "); scanf("%c",&op );
                        flush_in ();

                    if (answ_tf (op,lvl) == 1){
                        printf ("\n |Y| Has acertado!");

                        getchar ();
                        answer (op,lvl);
                        system ("clear");
                    }
                    else {
                        printf ("\n |N| Te has equivocado!\n");
                        intento ++;
                        getchar ();
                    }
                }
            }

    }while (intento <=6);
```

Debajo coloque:

```
if (aciertos == 6 && verify_words () == 0 && winner == 1){//si el usuario acerto en todas las palabras
        printf (" |Y| Has Ganado!!! \n |#| Completaste 6/6 palabras.\n");
        getchar ();
        return 0;
    }

    else if (aciertos < 6 && verify_words () == 0 && winner == 0){//si el usuario acerto algunas y ya agoto las palabras
        printf (" |Y| Has perdido... :'( \n |#| Completaste %i/6 palabras.\n",aciertos);
        getchar ();
        return 0;
    }
```